# use php array in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

my php code looks like this:

```
$result['firstName']['lastName']='johan';
echo json_encode($result);
```

how should i type to use this array in javascript with jquery?

```
...function(data) {
    alert(data.firstName.lastName);
});
```

or

```
...function(data) {
    alert(data.firstName['lastName']);
});
```

Comment: Did you try those out? Experiment! Experimentation never did any harm, ever. Not once. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JQuery doesn't effect object access, so you can just do

```
data.firstName.lastName
```

Comment: In my case after echo the $data i got an alert johan :-)

Comment: what do you mean with "doesn't affect object access"

Comment: @noname, I was just saying that introducing jQuery doesn't change the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't technically have associative arrays, so technically in Javascript you're working with an Object.  Either syntax you used should work.

Comment: Technically, every instance of Object is an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

The object['property'] syntax is only needed in javascript for numbers or syntactically ambiguous keys (e.g. those containing spaces).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me but its very ugly

```
<?php

$result['firstName']['lastName']='johan';
$data =  json_encode($result);

?>
<html>
<body onload='myfunction(<?php echo $data; ?>);'>
<script>
function myfunction(data) 
{
alert(data.firstName.lastName);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```